# How to Push/call the getSelectedIndex value from StateChanged method to another method/class?

Tags: java, swing, class, methods, jtabbedpane

I want to push/call the selected tab index value from the StateChanged method to another class or private method, How can I do this,

```
    private class TabSelect implements ChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JTabbedPane source = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
        if (source.getSelectedComponent() != null) {
            source.getSelectedIndex();

        }

    }
}
```

I want to push this index value to the following method (or another public class in the same package). How to do this?

```
private JPanel CreateSlice() {

        JPanel Slice = new JPanel();
        Slice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
        Slice.add(button);
        return Slice;

    }
```

This is the CreateSlice's function,

```
private class TabPlus implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JPanel panel = CreateSlice();
        String title = "Slice " + String.valueOf(pane.getTabCount());
        pane.insertTab(title, null, panel, null, pane.getTabCount() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you pass any variable between classes, use a method

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, I have a doubt, in case you can help me, I am a newbie and have already passed the whole week to think about it. I will post a question.

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    JTabbedPane source = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
    if (source.getSelectedComponent() != null) {
       int index =  source.getSelectedIndex();
       CreateSlice(index);
    }

}



public JPanel CreateSlice(int index) {
        //do whatever you want with index
        JPanel Slice = new JPanel();
        Slice.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 600));
        Slice.add(button);
        return Slice;

    }
```

note that your CreateSlice method should be public

Comment: But I am calling this CreateSlice to create panel in ActionListener method, if I set int index as parameter, then it shows error there,

I am giving that part in my question,

Answer (score 0):

```
int index =  source.getSelectedIndex(); // Save it to variable

createSlice(index); // pass it into new method, follow camelCase for bestPractice

 private JPanel createSlice(int index) {
   //your implementation
 }
```

Comment: But My CreateSlice is being used by ActionListener to create Panels. if I set int index as parameter, it shows error there.

Comment: so what do you want to do with your index, create other public method in the class .

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a situation since I don't know how to do this, There's a addTab method to add tab using a plus button, this method is calling CreateSlice method to create tab panels. Now I want to create some components on those tab panels. These panels might have different components in different tabs. Could I explain you well ? How can I do this, any idea?